# JavaScript library not working in IE, can't see error information

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have been writing a JavaScript library for a few weeks now and it works brilliantly in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. I had not tested it in IE until recently. I do not own a Windows box so after testing it on my friends and realising it wasnt working I started going over my code for things that could be causing it to break.

So far I have found nothing. I could not find any descriptions of the errors in the browser while I was there either. So I wondered if anyone could run my test script in an IE browser (6, 7 or 8) and let me know any information they can find as to why it crashed.

Please ignore any information saying it works in IE6, I put that up there after testing it through http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/

I just assumed it was working because I could set transparency and size via my script and see it run in this tool.

Here is the link to my GitHub repository: https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark

If you download it and run `spark.html` it will attempt to run all of my functions from the library.

So if anyone could be kind enough to run it in IE and either let me know what errors they are getting and possibly how to fix them then I will be extreamly grateful.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is it's website http://sparkjs.co.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Wed, 3 Nov 2010 11:19:20 UTC

Message: Access is denied.

Line: 1
Char: 17102
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/.........../Wolfy87-Spark-v0.2.5-19-gab64629/Wolfy87-Spark-ab64629/spark.js

The problem is when trying to load README.md file.
It's an issue related to permission as you see above. 
everything except loading and printing this file is OK on IE8.

Comment: Ah okay, so this could be down to just the AJAX module. Now we are getting somewhere. If you try removing the AJAX call from `spark.html` which is near the bottom and commented with `// AJAX module` does it work?

Comment: Yeah ,It worked. this what I commented out
// AJAX module
//s.content('p.readme', s.ajax('GET', 'README.md'));

Comment: Interesting, you may have found the problem! So even the opacity fading in and out, the resizing of that box in the middle. Every thing works apart from that?

Comment: @Wolfy: well, this sounds to me as a problem caused by the fact that Memo is testing this locally using the `file:` protocol; XMLHttpRequests can better be tested using a real web server (e.g., using a local webserver so you can test your scripts on `http://localhost/`).

Comment: I have uploaded it to my site, should have done this in the first place! How is this working? http://flowdev.co.uk/spark.html

Comment: @Wolfy: I found another problem on that page: in FF 4.0beta6 when I change the width that grey box, the box itself is resized, but the rounded corner parts aren't.

Comment: Yes I know about that one, I just havent implemented it yet, I just need to make it re'corner when it is resized :) that will be in all browsers. So does that direct link I added work?

Comment: I tested it using both local web server and locally (file) .if you commented out that line so everything would go fine.

Comment: Ah okay. The opacity wont be working in IE becuase it is not setting the zoom property (IE bug, blegh!), I had told it to do so but have uploaded a slightly older version that does not include the fix, so as long as you are not being bombarded with errors then you have found the problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: After using jslint I found a spelling error, I have it check if you are on IE and if you are then it does ajax differently, I had `XMLHTT` rather than `XMLHTTP`, this may have been the whole problem. Its always one character thats missing >_>

Answer (score 1):

I haven't IE6 right now, but I copied the js file in https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/master/spark.js then I pasted into http://www.jslint.com.

It seems you have a lot of syntax errors, so as first move you should check if any of those mistakes could generate an error on IE

After that, provide a not-minified and not-compressed version of javascript file, otherwise it's difficult to read your code.

Comment: Okay, uploaded an uncompressed version, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: jslint doesn't just give you syntax errors, it also looks for stylistic and code quality problems - and running it on a compressed script will definitely get you a lot of problems

Comment: Well after running the uncompressed version through jslint it came up with a lot of errors, I am not sure I am going to be able to go through all of these. Was there anything that stood out to you? Because alot of them seem to be to do with passing functions that are not encased in curly braces.

Comment: @Wolf: Indeed, most of the errors are because you don't use statement blocks in `if` clauses everywhere (which is indeed not needed). And I don't see an option in JSLint to ignore those "errors".

Comment: Wow, jslint sure is picky, I thought that was a standard in all languages. It is just a one line if statement.